# Weird instructions

Tags: fuzzing, memory, instrumentation

In fuzzing (with Pintool) to get examining execution traces of the program, here it is wget. I get some weird instructions, following is a piece extracted from a (very long) trace:

```
RIP register   instruction

0x7fff751fed17 mov rbx, 0xffffffffffdff000
0x7fff751fed1e lsl r11d, eax
0x7fff751fed22 xor r15d, r15d
0x7fff751fed25 mov r10d, r11d
0x7fff751fed28 mov r9d, dword ptr [0xff5ff080]
0x7fff751fed30 test r9b, 0x1
0x7fff751fed34 jnz 0x7fff1fdb4fdf
0x7fff751fed3a mov rax, qword ptr [0xff5ff0a8]
0x7fff751fed42 mov r13d, dword ptr [0xff5ff088]
0x7fff751fed4a mov qword ptr [rdi], rax
0x7fff751fed4d mov edx, dword ptr [0xff5ff088]
0x7fff751fed54 mov r14, qword ptr [0xff5ff0b0]
```

To me, they are quite weird. First, some of them access directly to the memory, that means some addresses, e.g. `0xff5ff080`, `0xff5ff0a8` have been hard-coded into the program. Second, I find them nowhere in the loaded libraries and wget itself. Third, even more weird, by passing the parameter `(IARG_MEMORYREAD_EA)` to get the virtual addresses of the accessed memories. I got the addresses, e.g. `0xffffffffff5ff080`, `0xffffffffff5ff0a8`, etc, and all of them do not belong to the program's memory space.

Coud anyone give me some suggestions ?.

Comment: Do you have the opcode bytes for these instructions? What is the EIP? Is in in the wget binary itself or in one of the shared objects?

Comment: Thank you, but the EIP seems normal. I have edited the question to add the EIP values. These instructions are in the binary itself.

Comment: It looks like you jumped in between an instruction. Means your disassembler interprets the opcodes completely wrong. For example this can happen when you overwritten return addresses through your fuzzing.

Comment: Thank you, I doubt that is the problem. Because before this happens, I see an indirect jump: "jmp qword ptr [rip+0x21388a]", and after several instructions, all become messy.

Comment: Unfortunately, by logging its static trace, namely before fuzzing, I see that these instructions exist. In case of you want to take a look, I give this [trace here](https://gist.github.com/tathanhdinh/7573904)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is code from the [vDSO](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/stable/vdso) which is mapped by the kernel into every process, not from the wget binary. You could probably figure it out by inspecting the `/proc/<pid>/maps` file.

Here's what I have in IDA for `gettimeofday` from it:

```
.text:FFFFFFFFFF700D17   mov     rbx, 0FFFFFFFFFFDFF000h
.text:FFFFFFFFFF700D1E   lsl     r11d, eax
.text:FFFFFFFFFF700D22   xor     r15d, r15d
.text:FFFFFFFFFF700D25   mov     r10d, r11d
.text:FFFFFFFFFF700D28   mov     r9d, ds:0FFFFFFFFFF5FF080h
.text:FFFFFFFFFF700D30   test    r9b, 1
.text:FFFFFFFFFF700D34   jnz     loc_FFFFFFFFFF700FDF
.text:FFFFFFFFFF700D3A   mov     rax, ds:0FFFFFFFFFF5FF0A8h
.text:FFFFFFFFFF700D42   mov     r13d, ds:0FFFFFFFFFF5FF088h
.text:FFFFFFFFFF700D4A   mov     [rdi], rax
.text:FFFFFFFFFF700D4D   mov     edx, ds:0FFFFFFFFFF5FF088h
.text:FFFFFFFFFF700D54   mov     r14, ds:0FFFFFFFFFF5FF0B0h
```

So it seems PIN's disassembler chose to not sign-extend addresses (which are encoded in 4 bytes in the opcodes).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Igor Skochinsky, you really made my day. I have never heard about vDSO before.